# Can't Install Bodog Poker Client

Tags: wine, kde

I cant seem to be able to run the BodogPoker Client at all on Kubuntu 11.04x64.

I get no errors during installation but get the following message when trying to run the software. [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21675) says their should be no problems installing this program, but a slight workaround when the program is first run.

Any help any one can provide would be very much appreciated.  Thank You.

**EDIT:**

1. wine version 1.2.3
2. i'm not exactly sure what version of the poker client it is but i got it directly from the offical bodog website and here is the link: http://poker.bodog.eu/how-to-play/download-poker.html
3. this is what i get when trying to run wine bodog through the terminal:

Trace output:

```
sanish@kedge14:~$ wine "c:\program files\bodog poker\bpgame.exe"
wine: Call from 0x7b839f22 to unimplemented function msvcp80.dll.??0?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@QAE@PBG@Z, aborting                      
wine: Unimplemented function msvcp80.dll.??0?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@QAE@PBG@Z called at address 0x7b839f22 (thread 0009), starting debugger...                                                                                                                                                                 
Unhandled exception: unimplemented function msvcp80.dll.??0?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@QAE@PBG@Z called in 32-bit code (0x7b839f22).     
Register dump:                                                                                                                                                            
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b                                                                                                                          
 EIP:7b839f22 ESP:0032fd0c EBP:0032fd70 EFLAGS:00200287(   - --  I S - -P-C)                                                                                              
 EAX:7b825ef1 EBX:7b893ff4 ECX:7e13a523 EDX:0032fd34                                                                                                                      
 ESI:80000100 EDI:00762418                                                                                                                                                
Stack dump:                                                                                                                                                               
0x0032fd0c:  0032fd90 00000008 0075f480 80000100                                                                                                                          
0x0032fd1c:  00000001 00000000 7b839f22 00000002                                                                                                                          
0x0032fd2c:  7e133ff4 7e13a523 00762418 0032fd48                                                                                                                          
0x0032fd3c:  7bc65b1b 7e0c7ff4 0076395c 0032fd68                                                                                                                          
0x0032fd4c:  7e2db971 0002e81f 00847634 0076395c                                                                                                                          
0x0032fd5c:  7e270ff4 7e2db960 7b839eda 7e270ff4                                                                                                                          
Backtrace:                                                                                                                                                                
=>0 0x7b839f22 in kernel32 (+0x29f22) (0x0032fd70)                                                                                                                        
  1 0x7e133f98 in msvcp80 (+0x23f97) (0x0032fda0)                                                                                                                         
  2 0x7e11fd5d in msvcp80 (+0xfd5c) (0x0032fe08)                                                                                                                          
  3 0x0075e670 in bpgame (+0x35e66f) (0x0032fe08)                                                                                                                         
  4 0x00474486 in bpgame (+0x74485) (0x0032fe90)                                                                                                                          
  5 0x7b8598bc call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0032fea8)                                                                                                          
  6 0x7b85a95f in kernel32 (+0x4a95e) (0x0032fee8)                                                                                                                        
  7 0x7bc72158 call_thread_func+0xb() in ntdll (0x0032fef8)                                                                                                               
  8 0x7bc758ee in ntdll (+0x658ed) (0x0032ffc8)
  9 0x7bc49c9e call_dll_entry_point+0x61d() in ntdll (0x0032ffe8)
0x7b839f22: subl        $4,%esp
Modules:
Module  Address                 Debug info      Name (133 modules)
PE        330000-  36e000       Deferred        ssleay32
PE        370000-  3d1000       Deferred        bptune
PE        3e0000-  3fe000       Deferred        bpemfloader
PE        400000-  86e000       Export          bpgame
PE        870000-  8a3000       Deferred        bpbase
PE        8b0000-  8c4000       Deferred        bpurl
PE        8d0000-  8e0000       Deferred        bptime
PE        8e0000-  8e7000       Deferred        bptranslated
PE        8f0000-  8fc000       Deferred        bpplayer
PE        900000-  908000       Deferred        bphumaninput
PE        910000-  928000       Deferred        bpmenu
PE        930000-  93a000       Deferred        bpsite
PE        940000-  97b000       Deferred        bpresource
PE        980000-  a16000       Deferred        fmod
PE       1160000- 1172000       Deferred        bptranslatedcore
PE      10000000-1011e000       Deferred        libeay32
PE      5d360000-5d36e000       Deferred        mfc80enu
PE      781d0000-782df000       Deferred        mfc80
ELF     7b800000-7b9a8000       Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7b9a8000       \               kernel32
ELF     7bc00000-7bcc3000       Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcc3000       \               ntdll
ELF     7bf00000-7bf04000       Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF     7d50c000-7d515000       Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF     7d515000-7d552000       Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF     7d552000-7d557000       Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF     7d557000-7d568000       Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
ELF     7d568000-7d56c000       Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF     7d56c000-7d57c000       Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF     7d57c000-7d5f0000       Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF     7d5f0000-7d686000       Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF     7d686000-7d6aa000       Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF     7d6aa000-7d758000       Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF     7d758000-7d788000       Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF     7d788000-7d7d2000       Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF     7d969000-7d99d000       Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d970000-7d99d000       \               uxtheme
ELF     7d99d000-7d9a3000       Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF     7d9a3000-7d9ad000       Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF     7d9ad000-7d9bc000       Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF     7d9bc000-7d9c0000       Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF     7d9c0000-7d9c8000       Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF     7d9c8000-7d9d2000       Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF     7d9d2000-7d9d8000       Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF     7d9d8000-7d9dc000       Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF     7d9dc000-7d9fe000       Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d9e0000-7d9fe000       \               imm32
ELF     7d9fe000-7da04000       Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF     7da04000-7da08000       Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF     7da08000-7da21000       Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF     7da21000-7da26000       Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF     7da26000-7db41000       Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF     7db41000-7db50000       Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF     7db50000-7db68000       Deferred        libice.so.6
ELF     7db68000-7db70000       Deferred        libsm.so.6
ELF     7db70000-7db78000       Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF     7db78000-7db84000       Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF     7db8e000-7db92000       Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF     7db94000-7dc3b000       Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7dba0000-7dc3b000       \               winex11
ELF     7dd5d000-7dd87000       Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF     7dd87000-7ddb6000       Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF     7ddb6000-7de3c000       Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF     7de3c000-7de51000       Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF     7de75000-7de97000       Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7de80000-7de97000       \               iphlpapi
ELF     7de97000-7dec0000       Deferred        msvfw32<elf>
  \-PE  7dea0000-7dec0000       \               msvfw32
ELF     7dec0000-7df01000       Deferred        avifil32<elf>
  \-PE  7ded0000-7df01000       \               avifil32
ELF     7df01000-7df3a000       Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7df10000-7df3a000       \               winspool
ELF     7df3a000-7e02e000       Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7df40000-7e02e000       \               comdlg32
ELF     7e02e000-7e105000       Deferred        msvcp90<elf>
  \-PE  7e050000-7e105000       \               msvcp90
ELF     7e105000-7e1b6000       Dwarf           msvcp80<elf>
  \-PE  7e110000-7e1b6000       \               msvcp80
ELF     7e1b6000-7e1ed000       Deferred        libncurses.so.5
ELF     7e1ed000-7e27a000       Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7e200000-7e27a000       \               msvcrt
ELF     7e2c3000-7e2f2000       Deferred        msvcr90<elf>
  \-PE  7e2d0000-7e2f2000       \               msvcr90
ELF     7e2f2000-7e31d000       Deferred        msvcr80<elf>
  \-PE  7e300000-7e31d000       \               msvcr80
ELF     7e31d000-7e34f000       Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e320000-7e34f000       \               ws2_32
ELF     7e34f000-7e441000       Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e370000-7e441000       \               oleaut32
ELF     7e441000-7e4b5000       Deferred        gdiplus<elf>
  \-PE  7e450000-7e4b5000       \               gdiplus
ELF     7e4b5000-7e4da000       Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7e4c0000-7e4da000       \               mpr
ELF     7e4da000-7e4ef000       Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF     7e4f8000-7e513000       Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  7e500000-7e513000       \               wsock32
ELF     7e513000-7e57e000       Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7e520000-7e57e000       \               wininet
ELF     7e57e000-7e673000       Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e590000-7e673000       \               comctl32
ELF     7e673000-7e6dc000       Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e680000-7e6dc000       \               shlwapi
ELF     7e6dc000-7e8ec000       Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e6f0000-7e8ec000       \               shell32
ELF     7e8ec000-7e900000       Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7e8f0000-7e900000       \               msimg32
ELF     7e900000-7e929000       Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e910000-7e929000       \               msacm32
ELF     7e929000-7e99e000       Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e930000-7e99e000       \               rpcrt4
ELF     7e99e000-7eaa4000       Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9b0000-7eaa4000       \               ole32
ELF     7eaa4000-7eb04000       Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eab0000-7eb04000       \               advapi32
ELF     7eb04000-7eba9000       Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb10000-7eba9000       \               gdi32
ELF     7eba9000-7ece6000       Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7ebc0000-7ece6000       \               user32
ELF     7ece6000-7ed88000       Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7ecf0000-7ed88000       \               winmm
ELF     7ef88000-7ef94000       Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF     7ef94000-7ef9f000       Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF     7ef9f000-7efb6000       Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF     7efb6000-7efdc000       Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF     7efe7000-7f000000       Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000       \               version
ELF     f7458000-f745c000       Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF     f745c000-f75b9000       Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF     f75b9000-f75d2000       Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF     f75d8000-f75e0000       Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF     f75f6000-f7737000       Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF     f7739000-f7757000       Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF     f7757000-f7758000       Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) C:\program files\bodog poker\bpgame.exe
        00000009    0 <==
0000000e services.exe
        0000001c    0
        00000016    0
        00000015    0
        00000014    0
        00000010    0
        0000000f    0
00000011 winedevice.exe
        00000018    0
        00000017    0
        00000013    0
        00000012    0
00000019 plugplay.exe
        0000001d    0
        0000001b    0
        0000001a    0
0000001e explorer.exe
        0000001f    0
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7b839f22 in kernel32 (+0x29f22) (0x0032fd70)
  1 0x7e133f98 in msvcp80 (+0x23f97) (0x0032fda0)
  2 0x7e11fd5d in msvcp80 (+0xfd5c) (0x0032fe08)
  3 0x0075e670 in bpgame (+0x35e66f) (0x0032fe08)
  4 0x00474486 in bpgame (+0x74485) (0x0032fe90)
  5 0x7b8598bc call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0032fea8)
  6 0x7b85a95f in kernel32 (+0x4a95e) (0x0032fee8)
  7 0x7bc72158 call_thread_func+0xb() in ntdll (0x0032fef8)
  8 0x7bc758ee in ntdll (+0x658ed) (0x0032ffc8)
  9 0x7bc49c9e call_dll_entry_point+0x61d() in ntdll (0x0032ffe8)
wine: Call from 0x7b839f22 to unimplemented function msvcp80.dll.??0?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@QAE@PBG@Z, aborting
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

WineHQ says that it is a bronze rated application with Wine version 1.3.22.  The error you have says that the Microsoft compatible DLL which has been recoded by Wine is missing a particular function.  It is likely that 1.3.x has this function coded in its version.

Can I make two suggestions:

1. If you have a valid Windows license - look for a DLL called "msvcp80.dll".  Copy that DLL probably to ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32.  Then use `winecfg` to override the inbuilt msvcp80 DLL
2. Alternatively, uninstall version wine 1.2 and install version 1.3.x from Software Center.  This usually is the latest development version of Wine - you need to be aware, updates are usually made every two weeks and sometimes software breakages can occur.